# Alerting configuration on sequential jobs on Rundeck

Tags: workflow, sequential, rundeck, alerts, opsgenie

I am trying to configure some alerts on sequential jobs, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I don't want to receive alerts when jobs D or E fails. I just want to be alerted when jobs A,B or C fails.

This is my job workflow:

The main job E calls job A and B then B calls job C and C calls D.

The alerts are configured as below:

A (Configured to alert)
B (Configured to alert)
C (Configured to alert)
D (NOT Configured to alert)
E (NOT Configured to alert)

The issue is that when job D fails I am receiving alerts stating that job A, B and C failed even if they succeed

I am trying to set some alerts individually on the sequential jobs to get notifications just when specific job fails

Answer (score 0):

You have a job workflow with multiple sequential jobs, and you want to set up alerts for specific job failures. The main job, E, calls job A and B. Job B, in turn, calls job C, and job C calls job D.

You want to receive alerts only when jobs A, B, or C fail, and you do not want to be alerted for job D or job E failures.

To achieve this, you need to configure the alerts as follows:

Job A: Configure the alert to notify you when it fails.
Job B: Configure the alert to notify you when it fails.
Job C: Configure the alert to notify you when it fails.
Job D: Do not configure any alerts for this job.
Job E: Do not configure any alerts for this job.
Ensure that the alerts are set up specifically for failure events. Check the settings to make sure you haven't accidentally selected any other triggers or conditions for the alerts.

With these configurations, you should only receive notifications when jobs A, B, or C fail. You will not receive any alerts for job D or job E.

Comment: Hi Devin, I have double checked and the alerts are configured as you stated.
I notice the ${job.status} variable is RUNNING when I receive the alert.